# He started off as......and/but ended up (becoming) successful

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

"He started off as an ordinary entrepreneur **but/and** ended up **(becoming)** one of the wealthiest men in town."

Q1)I'm sure 'and' is used in such context, but can 'but' be used in this context as well?
Q2) Since we say "he ended up broke" can becoming be omitted?

Answer (score 1):

The word "becoming" can be omitted in either 1 or 2. "Ended up" describes the end of a process, while "becoming" describes the process. You don't need both. You could use "became" in place of "ended up"
Whether you use "and" or "but" depends on whether you want to draw a contrast between the two clauses. Since you used the word "ordinary" in the first clause, you could use "but" if you wanted to contrast that with the superlative "wealthiest" in the second clause. A "but" would be even more fitting where he "ended up broke".
By the way, "one of the wealthiest ..." requires the plural "men".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the correction. I think I get it. I think 'and' fits this sentence better- "He started off as a wealthy businessman and ended up an wealthier one." Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That makes sense.